# Create new Column and fill it with column from other dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to fill the new dataframe with values from the main source. If the ID is not the same, I want to fill the entry with `NEWCUSTOMER`. I tried followed, but it throws an error that the Column is not iterable.

***Task:***
I have "old" customers and "new" customers. My goal is to categorize the "new" customers in testC without a customerID as "NEWCUSTOMER" if a customerID exists for the customers (in train), then it should give the customer in testC the value of customerCategory from train.

```
train.show(1)
testC = testC.withColumn("customerCategory", F.when(testC.customerID.contains(train.customerID),\
                                                    F.col(train.customerCategory)).otherwise("NEWCUSTOMER"))

+-----------+----------+------------+------+----+-----+--------------+-----+----------+----------+-----------+------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|orderItemID| orderDate|deliveryDate|itemID|size|color|manufacturerID|price|customerID|salutation|dateOfBirth| state|creationDate|returnShipment|customerCategory|
+-----------+----------+------------+------+----+-----+--------------+-----+----------+----------+-----------+------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|        148|2012-04-01|  2012-04-04|   651|  xl| blue|            46| 19.9|      1121|       Mrs|          ?|Berlin|  2012-04-01|             0|           GREEN|
+-----------+----------+------------+------+----+-----+--------------+-----+----------+----------+-----------+------+------------+--------------+----------------+
TypeError: Column is not iterable
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<command-3715636189631646> in <module>
  1 train.show(1)
  2 testC = testC.withColumn("customerCategory", 
     F.when(testC.customerID.contains(train.customerID),\
  ----> 3  F.col(train.customerCategory)).otherwise("NEWCUSTOMER"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the starting dataset `testC` is not clear, but IIUC you could employ a left `join` and then use the `fillna` method only on the column of interest.

```
testC\
    .join(train, on='customerID', how='left')\
    .fillna('NEWCUSTOMER', subset=['customerCategory'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `LEFT JOIN`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

    train_df  = train\
.selectExpr('customerID as train_c_id', 'customerCategory as train_category' )\
.distinct()

mergedDF = train.join(testC, train['train_c_id']==testC['customerID'], how='left')

mergedDF = mergedDF.withColumn('customerCategory',\
 F.expr\
('case when customerID is not null then train_category else 'NEWCUSTOMER' END)
```